# Hiding elements based on data attribures?

Tags: html, css

I am just trying to play around with the widget on this [link](http://tsvetankea.co.nf/DocAp.php) and hide all the tabs on the top except "Flights", so I have one in the end instead of four.

I figured out the following CSS snippet for this, which is visible in the html on the link :

```
    [data-cf-product="FLIGHTSHOTELS"] { 
    display:none;
}
```

So I am just trying to hide the second `li` in the `ul` that has a `data attribute` with value `FLIGHTSHOTELS` with this code, but I have no idea why it isn't working. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[data-cf-selectedproduct="FLIGHTS"] > li:not(:nth-of-type(1)) {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I just tried it on the page from the link, but it's not working

Comment: Apologies - just checked the source and noticed it's an iframe. You won't be able to style content loaded in via iframe unless it's permitted (which in this case, it isn't).